# How to set gradient color to android notification

Tags: android, xamarin

I want to set the background of an android notification to a gradient color.

I found out that it is possible to set the color of notification with following lines:

```cs
using var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, channelInfo.Id); 
builder.SetColor(BackgroundColor()); 
builder.SetColorized(true);
```

For the gradient background i have created following drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
      android:type="linear"
      android:angle="0"
      android:startColor="#f6ee19"
      android:endColor="#115ede" />
</shape>
```

How can i use this drawable as background in the notification?

Comment: use `setBackground` instead.

Comment: The class ```NotificationCompat.Builder``` does not contain a method called ```SetBackground```

Comment: It is present in android class.

Comment: I cant find it. Even not documented here: [https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder)

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: sorry it available in wear only.

Comment: you need to try custom layout notification.
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification.html